# Initialize materializecss component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, materialize

I'm trying to add the Carousel image slider from MaterializeCSS to a simple React component but i'm not able to initialize it! It would be very helpful to know where i should do it in my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { M } from 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js';

export default class Slider extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
   var elem = document.querySelector('.carousel');
   var instance = M.Carousel.init(elem, { duration: 200 });
 }
render() {
 return (
  <div className="container center-align">
   <h1 className="header pink-text">Slider</h1>
    <div className="carousel">
      <a className="carousel-item" href="#one!">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" />
      </a>
      <a className="carousel-item" href="#two!">
        <img src="../../public/images/lana/1.jpg" />
      </a>
      <a className="carousel-item" href="#three!">
       <img src="../../public/images/lana/1.jpg" />
      </a>
      <a className="carousel-item" href="#four!">
       <img src="../../public/images/lana/1.jpg" />
      </a>
       <a className="carousel-item" href="#five!">
        <img src="../../public/images/lana/1.jpg" />
       </a>
     </div>
    </div>
  );
 }
}
```

this gives me an Error:
Cannot read property 'Carousel' of undefined

i tried to do it with Jquery, no errors but didn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using a `.min` file to import `M` from. You should install `MaterializeCSS` as a node module instead. You're getting an error because `M` is not defined as anything. There aren't any exports from that `.min` file.

If you want to wait until the script has loaded it is better to do that with a callback instead of `setTimeout`.

```
function loadScript(url, callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script")
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  if (callback) { 
    script.onload = callback; 
  }
  document.body.appendChild(script)
  script.src = url;
}


loadScript(pathtoscript, function() {
  alert('script ready!'); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, So regardless my code, how can i implement that 
MaterializeCSS JS  inside an application?

Comment: Instead of using `setTimeout` you should wait until the script has loaded and then execute a callback.

Comment: Thank you Jakub, you right i need to convert it to a callback,I need to fetch images from same directory and pass it to the Carousel, idk exactly how to do it!

Comment: If the answer helps you could you mark it as correct?

Comment: I did, if you like you can also help me with my specific situation : )

Comment: Sure just post in the comments and I'll try to help and update my answer if needed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

Solved it by adding the materializecss npm module

```
npm install materialize-css
```

and then importing it into the component

```
import M from "materialize-css";
```

and in the componentDidUpdate method, added the init

```
componentDidUpdate() {

    let collapsible = document.querySelectorAll(".collapsible");

    M.Collapsible.init(collapsible, {});
  }
```

Problem solved!!

Answer (score 2):

Using React Hook with **useEffect** you can also initialize each feature on Materialize, for example:

```
    import React, { useEffect, Fragment } from "react";

    import M from "materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js";
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Init Tabs Materialize JS
    let tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tabs");
    M.Tabs.init(tabs);
});
```

In my case, I used tabs to initialize the Materialize feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use min.js file in your application, try adding it in html file using  tag.

Alternatively try adding node modules using npm package.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I tried to add the CDN in the HTML and initialize it there also but didn't work!

Comment: did you try these -   <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yes, i did. i did similar project idea with normal html and it works fine, idk where i should initialize Materialize components inside React

Comment: Checkout this link-https://react-materialize.github.io/#/, for carousel, you might have to import like - import {Carousel} from 'react-materialize'

Comment: Thank you, Really appreciated

Comment: I will try it, it worked with me when i used setTimeout() function and call initialization within it

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it needs some time to render the content. When I use `setTimeout()` function and call that initialization JS lines it worked.

Comment: can you provide code snippet you used to get this working? as I am facing a similar problem init materialize with npm

Comment: please Blah, check my new comment, hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

I initialize the Carousel js code from the main html page with setTimeout() function, i used a spinner to make look little better

it looks like this

```
<script>

    setTimeout(() => {
      var elem = document.querySelector('.carousel');
      var instance = M.Carousel.init(elem, {});
      if (document.querySelector('.photos').classList) {
        document.querySelector('.photos').classList.remove("spinner")
      }
    }, 2000)
  </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

add window.M. ...

```
  useEffect(() => {
var elem = document.querySelector(".carousel");
var instance = window.M.Carousel.init(elem, {
  fullWidth: true,
  indicators: true,
});
```

});